# I want my keyframe animation to restart after some time

Tags: css-animations, reset, keyframe, seconds

#### Scenario:

I have an animation where my text will go black when my background video will go very bright.

#### Problem:

after the background video switches back to the beginning the text stay's black. How can I reset it again?

#### Goal:

I want my `keyframe` animation to restart after some seconds.

#### Question:

is a solution for this?

My code:
HTML:

```
    <div class="header-text">
    <h1 class="head-text">Rico Dijkstra</h1>
    <h2 class="head-desc">Front-end</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.head-text {
    font-family: 'Lato', ;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 4rem;
    animation-name: color-swap;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
.head-desc {
    font-family: 'Lato', ;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 3rem;
    animation-name: color-swap;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    margin-top: 0;
}

@keyframes color-swap {
    from {color: white;}
    to {color: black}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with jQuery SetInterval
For this you don't need to include animation css at the beginning
CSS:

```
.header-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.head-text {
    font-family: 'Lato', ;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 4rem;
}
.head-desc {
    font-family: 'Lato', ;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-top: 0;
}
@keyframes color-swap {
    from {color: white;}
    to {color: black}
```

jquery

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){ 
   $(".head-text .head-desc").css({
    "animation-name":"color-swap",
    "animation-duration": "3s",
    "animation-fill-mode": "forwards"})
  }, 3000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i edit the code. Please check console.. Is there any error??

Comment: Yeah I fixed an error but it still didn't work. It gives no error anymore.